# Rails querying by two attributes from same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, activerecord, rails-activerecord

Is there a way in Rails to query for a list of records by comparing two attributes from the same model?

I have a User model and I want to query for all users where the updated_at time is within 6 hours of the created_at time on the Users table.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you give `where` a string, it just turns into SQL. So you can say this:

```
User.where("updated_at - created_at <= interval '6 hours'")
```

That is in Postgres. MySQL should be similar but a little different.

Comment: Is it possible to add 2 hours to the created_at time?

Comment: Sure! :-) Actually that is the same as comparing to `interval '4 hours'`, right? I would spend a little time learning SQL, and test out these queries at a plain database prompt like `psql`, and then translate them into ActiveRecord when they are doing what you want. For example `SELECT * FROM users WHERE updated_at - created_at <= interval '4 hours'";`.